# How can I add JavaMail to the eclipse

Tags: java

I just downloaded javaMail 1.4 and moved the libs files to

%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext

i got error when i tried to use this library from eclipse as the image below has shown

http://i41.tinypic.com/2itor6e.png

thanks

Comment: It's not really good practice to install Java libraries systemwide like this – it makes collaborating on the project harder because everyone has to do the same setup steps correctly. Keep them in a `lib` directory in your project and add them using Project Properties.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this tutorial [Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

or

```
Properties-> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> click on Add External Jar/Folder
```

Answer (score 2):

If you working on **Eclipse**
Right click on your *project name* in the project tab, then go to

go to Project `Properties`-> Select the `Libraries` Tab -> Click on `Add Jar/Folder`

Then *Browse* and select your `.jar` file and click **OK**.
Now
The JARs will now appear in the list of libraries in the build path.

after that
*Clean* , *Build* and *Run*.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in that you should add the library to your project instead of putting in in jre/lib directory.

But if you **really** need it, go to

```
window-> preferences-> java-> compiler-> errors/warnings
```

and change the setting for `Forbidden reference` to `warning`.