# Need to add the javax.mail package to my eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-mail

I want to create a basic java application where I **send** and **receive** an **email**, but my Eclipse doesn't recognize the `javax.mail` package which I need for the code.

I've downloaded the package, but I can't figure out how to add it to my Eclipse.

I also would prefer that it gets added to my Eclipse workspace and not just to the one project that I am doing, as I will need the package later for other projects.

**How do I install the package?** I don't know how to properly use things like class paths and command prompts etc, so I need a step by step help if it requires that.

Comment: The only way I know you can possibly add it to eclipse and every project on it would be to add it directly into your JAVA_HOME lib folder. That way whenever you create a new project the library will be available. But this is not the right way. You should use a project management software as Apache Maven to handle your projects dependencies.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into a build system like gradle.  You can set yourself up with a very small build file which will let you define dependencies such as javax.mail and then not worry about it

Comment: What is this "package" you haven't given any details on? What have you tried so far? You seem to be asking for someone to write you a tutorial on the spot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add JavaMail to the eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068380/how-can-i-add-javamail-to-the-eclipse)

Comment: Using a search engine the solution to this problem is not far away: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068380/how-can-i-add-javamail-to-the-eclipse. And please also take the time to learn what you said you don't know much about

Answer (score 2):

If that's really what you want to do, go to **Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries**.

Then press `new...` give it a name and add the **jars**, which should be ideally located in an appropriate place that makes sense to you and especially not in the JRE directory.

---

Then you can use those libraries in any new project. For that go to `properties` of the project, `Java Build Path` and add the libraries in the (surprise) `Libraries` tab.

---

But I think you would be better off using **Maven**, **Gradle** or any other build tool in your projects. However if a library is not publicly available in a repository, and you must download the jars, then this a reasonable option.

---

Here are some images illustrating the process:

**1. How to add new libraries to Eclipse**

[image: Eclipse dialog for adding user libraries]

**2. Edit library settings (adding source, javadoc and so on)**

[image: Eclipse dialog for changing library settings]

**3. Add your user library to a project**

[image: Eclipse dialog for adding libraries to projects]